# How to store id of another document in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I think of two ways: storing it as a string and convert it to mongoId object if necessary or store it directly as an object. Which method is preferred and why?

Comment: `MongoId` is normally the best method, or if you dunno the other table and want a standardised object `DBRef`

Comment: It's best to store `ObjectID` as `ObjectID` datatype, rather than as a string.